# ASP.NET WebApi - how do I post a collection to a WebApi method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

As I understand it, if I have an ASP.NET WebApi method whose signature looks like this...

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer) {
  // code to handle the POSTed customer goes here
}
```

..then the WebApi model binding will look through the form collection and see if it has entries that match the names of the properties on the Customer class, and bind them to a new instance of the class, which gets passed in to the method.

What if I want to allow some to POST a collection of objects? In other words, I want to have a WebApi method that looks like this...

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomers(IEnumerable<Customer> customers) {
  // code to handle the POSTed customers goes here
}
```

How would the calling code set up the POST?

The same question applies if I want the Customer object to have a property that is a collection, say the customer's orders. How would the HTTP POST be set up?

The reason for the question is that I want to write a controller that will allow someone using Delphi to POST information to my server. Don't know if that is relevant, but thought I better mention it in case. I can see how he could do this for a single object (see first code snippet), but can't see how he would do it for the collection.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Are you going for a RESTful pattern?  If so, operations should be at a singleton level.

Comment: To be honest, I'm going for the easiest way to make it work! The Delphi developer wants to send up a whole pile of data in one go, hence the question. I don't mind things coming in one at a time, but he says that's going to cause him problems. I would like to allow him to send up a collection if possible. Can that be done? Thanks

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: what are you specifically looking for? like how the format of the request would look like? can your Delphi client send data in Json format? if yes an example of how a collection of objects in json would look like is [{"Age":10,"Id":1},{"Age":35,"Id":2},{"Age":23,"Id":3}]

Comment: But how would he set up the HTTP POST request? The way I've always done this before is that you add an entry for each form field, so a "contact us" form would have "name", "telephone" etc fields, and the HTTP POST request would be set up by adding an entry for "name" with the data in it, one for "telephone" with that data in and so on. That's fine when it's a fixed number of fields, known in advance, but when you want to post an unknown number of things, such as a collection of customers, how would he set up the POST? Thx.

Comment: Isn't that a Delphi specific question? Also if you are planning to send deep structured data, why not send it in Json. You should check if Delphi has libraries to serialize content into formurlencoded or Json.

Comment: No, it's a general question about how to use the WebApi, and is equally relevant to someone using .NET. The question is, if the controller method expects a collection of objects, how do I set up the POST request. I'm not looking for specific code for Delphi, PHP, etc, I'm looking for information on how the HTTP POST request would be formed. That is independent of the technology being used to make the request. As for JSon, I don't see that it has any advantages in terms of the depth. XML is perfectly capable of deep structures, it just uses more bandwidth, but is what they want to use.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCustomer(IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    db.Customers.AddRange(customers);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Client code to POST multiple entities:

```
 public async Task<string> PostMultipleCustomers()
 {
        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer { Name = "John Doe" },
            new Customer { Name = "Jane Doe" },
        };
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://<Url>/api/Customers", customers);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            }
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();              
         }
}
```

Comment: How does this help? I asked how to set up the HTTP post from the consumer of the web API call. You have shown code for the Web API itself, which was never the problem.